# No coding experience, struggling to install a java based application called Edgewonk

Tags: java

Here is the official guide:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-PVKD_Dz9CM&feature=emb_title

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64bit
Gnome: 3.36.1
Windowing: X11
OpenJRE is installed

Thanks for any directions. Will gladly tip some cryptocurrency if that is allowed.

Comment: If you want to execute a .jar file you can open a terminal in your download directory , and run the command " java -jar some_file.jar " . In that video , the rest of the process is quite straightforward.

Comment: This is one of the classes of the program itself . So I don't think you can install it via your repository or a package manager . Are you sure it is downloaded correctly ?

Comment: Just clicked download and have the .jar file on the desktop. Am able to select it with JRE but when I try to execute, nothing happens.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: Still an open question.